# how to execute mapsforge map 0.3.0 sample

Tags: android, dictionary

it have following **missing** imports

```
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Polygon;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.PolygonalChain;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Polyline;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.ListOverlay;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Marker;
import org.mapsforge.core.BoundingBox;
import org.mapsforge.core.GeoPoint;
```

i just include some other jar as well but its no use 
**mapsforge-map-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies** the code is not executing any more

Comment: you can also use the correct svn version (March 2012) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are was lots of missing files that we have to add throw Maven 
step by step procediore is .

- step 0.

Source Checkout [page to download](http://mapsforge.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) the source code of the project to your computer.

- step 1.

uses the [free Apache maven tool](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) to automatize the build process.
[image]

- step 2.

you have to set all the variables

> Windows 2000/XP
>
> 1. Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
> 2. Add the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system properties (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the "Environment Variables" button, then adding the M2_HOME variable in the user variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4. Be sure to omit any quotation marks around the path even if it contains spaces. Note: For Maven < 2.0.9, also be sure that the M2_HOME doesn't have a '\' as last character.
> 3. In the same dialog, add the M2 environment variable in the user variables with the value %M2_HOME%\bin.
> 4. Optional: In the same dialog, add the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.
> 5. In the same dialog, update/create the Path environment variable in the user variables and prepend the value %M2% to add Maven available in the command line.
> 6. In the same dialog, make sure that JAVA_HOME exists in your user variables or in the system variables and it is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_02 and that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your Path environment variable.
> 7. RESTART MACHINE for windows to become aware of path changes
> 8. Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn --version to verify that it is correctly installed.

NOTE: you might need to change %M2% for the complete path C:\Program Files\Apache...\bin

> Unix-based Operating Systems
>   (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)
>
> Extract the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz
>   to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions
>   assume you chose /usr/local/apache-maven. The subdirectory
>   apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive. In a command
>   terminal, add the M2_HOME environment variable, e.g. export
>   M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4. Add the M2
>   environment variable, e.g. export M2=$M2_HOME/bin. Optional: Add the
>   MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to specify JVM properties, e.g. export
>   MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m". This environment variable can be used
>   to supply extra options to Maven. Add M2 environment variable to your
>   path, e.g. export PATH=$M2:$PATH. Make sure that JAVA_HOME is set to
>   the location of your JDK, e.g. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_02
>   and that $JAVA_HOME/bin is in your PATH environment variable. Run mvn
>   --version to verify that it is correctly installed.

- step 3

  open a command prompt, go to the checked out trunk directory and execute the following command:

> ```
> mvn clean install
> ```

- step 4

As Eclipse needs to know the path to your local maven repository, you have to add a new classpath variable named M2_REPO. This can either be done manually via Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables > New or automatically via the Maven [Eclipse Plugin.](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)